# Computer can't join AD over point-to-site VPN to domain controller VM in Azure

Tags: active-directory, vpn, azure

Error indicates DNS problem but all diagnostics indicate it is working fine.

> The following error occurred when DNS was queried for the service
> location (SRV) resource record used to locate an Active Directory
> Domain Controller (AD DC) for domain "fcp.local":
>
> The error was: "This operation returned because the timeout period
> expired." (error code 0x000005B4 ERROR_TIMEOUT)
>
> The query was for the SRV record for _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.fcp.local
>
> The DNS servers used by this computer for name resolution are not
> responding. This computer is configured to use DNS servers with the
> following IP addresses:
>
> 10.0.0.4
>
> Verify that this computer is connected to the network, that these are
> the correct DNS server IP addresses, and that at least one of the DNS
> servers is running.

> nslookup -type=SRV _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.fcp.local
> Server: fcp-ad.internal.cloudapp.net
> Address:  10.0.0.4
>
> _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.fcp.local  SRV service location:
> priority       = 0
> weight         = 100
> port           = 389
> svr hostname   = fcp-ad.fcp.local fcp-ad.fcp.local
> internet address = 10.0.0.4

> Test-NetConnection 10.0.0.4 -p 389
>
> ComputerName     : 10.0.0.4 RemoteAddress    : 10.0.0.4 RemotePort
> : 389 InterfaceAlias   : FCP-AD-vnet SourceAddress    : 10.1.0.130
> TcpTestSucceeded : True

> Test-NetConnection 10.0.0.4 -p 53
>
> ComputerName     : 10.0.0.4 RemoteAddress    : 10.0.0.4 RemotePort
> : 53 InterfaceAlias   : FCP-AD-vnet SourceAddress    : 10.1.0.130
> TcpTestSucceeded : True

Client and Domain Controller are Windows Server 2019

Azure Gateway VPN and Azure VPN Client

[NSG Security Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZanN.png)

Comment: Are you using an NSG? Azure Firewall? If so, what are the details of those? Can you otherwise connect to the Azure DC from the local network? If so, how? RDP? Is the Windows Firewall enabled on the Azure DC?

Comment: @joeqwery No Azure Firewall but there is NSG on the DC VM.  I allowed any traffic inbound or outbound from the VPN client address range to DC.  Yes, I can ping and RDP to 10.0.0.4 from the client PC.  Windows Firewall is turned on DC but network is private.

Comment: You need more than ports 53 and 389. You also need 135 and 49152-65535.

Comment: @GregAskew 135 is open

Test-NetConnection 10.0.0.4 -p 135
ComputerName     : 10.0.0.4
RemoteAddress    : 10.0.0.4
RemotePort       : 135
InterfaceAlias   : FCP-AD-vnet
SourceAddress    : 10.1.0.130
TcpTestSucceeded : True

49152-64435 should be open right?  I added an image to original question

Comment: How about  `nltest /dsgetdc: domain.com /server:IP address`

Comment: @GregAskew Thanks, maybe this is helpful
nltest /dsgetdc:fcp.local /server:10.0.0.4
Getting DC name failed: Status = 1722 0x6ba RPC_S_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE

Comment: That's not good. You should run a netmon or Wireshark capture during that and probably the domain join. Could be high port connectivity blocked, or blocked on the other side.

Answer (score 1):

For a client to reach a domain controller you need a site to site vpn, because the vpn needs to be available before user logon. A P2S vpn is started after a user logs on. For example group policy processing happens before user logon

Or always on vpn with a device tunnel https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-access/vpn/vpn-device-tunnel-config

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to resolve DNS name from your client using:

```
 nslookup <domain name>
```

If you are able to resolve the domain then you need to check if there already a computer account created with the same name as client, if yes then delete that computer account and then try to join.

Can you please share the error you are getting when the domain join operation is failed?

Comment: Both the error message from trying to join domain and successful nslookup are in original question.

The client computer is not already registered in the domain.